# What is the advantage of READ COMMITTED over READ UNCOMMITTED in Database Isolation level OR Why Dirty Read is considered so bad

Tags: database, concurrency, rdbms, isolation-level

I think choosing an Isolation level for a trasaction depends on the nature of transaction. But as far I have seen it is always advised to avoid (or say 'restricted') using READ_UNCOMMITTED. Most database uses READ_COMMITTED as default isolation level. Somehow I find myself slow to observe advantage of READ COMMITTED over READ UNCOMMITTED.

The only advantage of READ COMMITTED over READ UNCOMMITTED I see is READ COMMITTED wiil never do a DIRTY READ. I find DIRTY READ can make Database unconsistence only in case of a Transaction ROLLBACK(Transaction from which dirty read made). That implies in a part of a system where Transaction ROLLBACK is very unlikely (or say never) to happen READ UNCOMMITTED will give better performance over READ COMMITTED.

Lets take a case:
we have record A = 100; B = 200;

```
T1(READ_UNCOMMITTED)  |    T2
                      |    A = A + 100 //(A=200 NOW)
 READ(A); //200       |
 B = B + A //400      |
 COMMIT;              |
                      |    COMMIT;
```

The only way database will go unconsistence is Transaction T2 'ROLLBACK' occurs. Now if it is most unlikely of T2 to have a ROLLBACK than it seems to me as perfomance gain over little risk taken.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
This one is too long for a comment so @Quassnoi
Let us say we have two transaction T1 (session 1) and T2 (session 2). T2 takes database from a consistence state DB_S1 to DB_S2. As you already know T1 with READ_UNCOMMITTED may give a result that is not compilant with either DB_S1 or DB_S2. The same we may say about T1 with READ_COMMITTED.

```
Lets say a schedule: T1 starts, counts 100; 
T2 starts -> has updated row 1 to .9M ;
T1 starts -> counts 150
T2 starts -> finish update
T1 starts -> can't find anything where value = 1 hence finish.
```

T1 gives result as 150 which never existed.

I guess in this case T1 needs a Searializable Lock to guarantee a consistence result otherwise it would be on the mercy of transaction scheduler.

Comment: You don't need `SERIALIZABLE` for `t1`, `READ COMMITTED` would be enough. As soon as it encounters the first row / page locked by `t2` it will stop and wait for `t2` completion.

Comment: @Quassnoi are you sure, I tried on mysql with two sessions (different connection) where T2 gets a write lock but T1 still reads old value. Also in the case mentioned by you T1 will count to 100 and then see the committed data by T2, hence it will 100 as result which is still wrong. IMHO T1 needs a range lock.

Comment: `t1` and `t2` will not return unless they process all records in the table. `t1` will return either `0` or `1M` (or be rolled back as a result or deadlock resolution). Since `t1` will place shared locks on records already processed, `t2` will not be able to update those records, it will have to wait for `t1` to complete.

Comment: I have a test case, not for million records but still I simulate overlapping transaction boundaries.       T2(connection/session2){set autocommit = 0;
SET session TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL  READ COMMITTED;
start transaction;
update etm.test v set v.cost = '1111' where v.id = 1; /*notice no commit*/}                                             T1(connection/session1){set autocommit = 0;
SET session TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
start transaction;
select v.cost from etm.test v where v.id =1;/*reads old value*/}

Comment: @Quassnoi I guess you are right, if T1 demands for a share lock, it gonna give a result compliant to one of the consistence state. Also as per Sql99 it should ask a share lock, it seems its time for me to dig into MySql.

Comment: I was talking of `SQL Server`. `InnoDB` uses `MVCC` and does not allow dirty reads at all.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a table with 1M records, all record having `value = 1`

Then you run these two queries concurrently:

Session 1:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE   value = 1
```

Session 2:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     value = 2
WHERE   value = 1
```

In `SQL Server`, the first query would return an arbitrary number between `0` and `1,000,000`.

Comment: I want to know advantage of READ_COMMITTED over READ_UNCOMMITTED. In you example READ_COMMITTED will prevent DIRTY_READ only and but still session 1 may result into READ_UNREPEATABLE phenomenon for all the rows updated by session 2 which have been read by session 1. The scenario does not seems to be suitable for either READ_UNCOMMITTED or READ_COMMITTED.

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi: with `READ COMMITTED`, you will always get either `0` rows or `1M` for the first query. With `READ UNCOMMITTED`, you will get a random number brtween those two. This is probably not what you want with a first query.

Comment: I feel we may get a random number that never existed even with READ COMMITTED. Please see the new edit in question for my explaination